# Running a couple functions inside another one

Tags: python, function

I'd like to have a few functions run inside a 'primary' or my main function. I'd like to be using function1() as my main way to actually run what's happening...i.e i run my script, then use function1() to actually use my script.

So this is an example, which might make things a little clearer:

```
def move_ant(grid, ant_row, ant_col, orientation):

    orientation_and_colour_change(ant_row,ant_col,orientation)

    movement(ant_row,ant_col,orientation)

    return ant_row, ant_col, orientation
```

So I want to use moveant() with those 4 variable inputs, run the two functions below which use some of the input date from the 'primary' function, then return a 3-tuple as can be seen in the return line.

However, a few things:
I want the 2 inside functions to run in that precise order. So after I run in the command line `move_ant(bla,bla,bla,bla)`, I want `orientation_and_colour_change()` to be run first, and then `movement()` to be run. The only information that will change after passing the info through the `orientation_and_colour_change()` function will be the orientation, so I want to make sure that the `movement()` function is using the 'updated' orientation.
Is that possible?

Comment: Well, you'll have to make your inner functions *return* the modified values, but otherwise, the code should work exactly as you've described.

Comment: Why wouldn't they happen in order?

Comment: Is that the right formatting though? I'm getting a return from the move_ant function that is identical to the input, as if the info isn't even being passed through the other two functions. I know the functions run perfectly individually, I just want to use them in conjunction with each other, because I need `movement()` to be using the updated `orientation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can totally do that! You're example is kind of confusing, but I'll try to give you correct example code:

```
#define you functions
def move_ant(grid,row,col,orientation):
    row,col,orientation = orientation_and_color_change(row,col,orientation)#run function and return values.

    row,col,orientation = movement(row,col,orientation)#run function and return changed vals

    return row,col,orientation

def orientation_and_color_change(changeRow,changeCol,changeOrientation):
    #do stuff with the variables you've inputted
    return changeRow,changeCol,changeOrientation

def movement(moveRow,moveCol,moveOrientation):
    #do stuff with variables
    return changeRow,changeCol,changeOrientation
#RUN THE FUNCTION
#not sure how you have you're vars set up
grid = [10,30]#random numbers! Yay!
row = 1
col = 1
orientation = 0
row,col,orientation = move_ant(grid,row,col,orientation)
```

Don't forget, variables in a different function only exist within that function. That's called the **scope** of a variable. Look it up. It's important. if you want an outside variable to be changed by a function, you have to pass that variable into the function as a **paramater** (give the function a piece of information to work with) and then the function has to **return** that variable at the end (the function gives it back to the outer refernce).

That's why, when I run my function, I set variables equal to the function: `row,col,orientation = movement(row,col,orientation)`. The variables `row`, `col`, and `orientation` are set to collect and save whatever information the function hands back in the return statement, respectively: `return changeRow,changeCol,changeOrientation`

Does this make sense? Or did I completely miss the point?

Comment: This answer would be much better if you used Python's tuple unpacking features. Instead of doing `changeList = orientation_and_color_change(row,col,orientation)` and then unpacking `changeList` one step at a time, just go straight to `row, col, orientation = orientation_and_color_change(row, col, orientation)`.

Comment: Yeah I wrote this in 5 minutes and completely forgot about that. Thanks for the reminder! I'll go change it.

Comment: Both ways worked! I adjusted to the second one using the tuple unpacking features for a bit of clarity though. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The order that the functions would run is pretty much how it looks:  `orientation_and_colour_change()` will run before `movement()`.

However, you might have a problem with the values of your arguments: `ant_row`, `ant_col`, `orientation`, because you're running those functions but doing nothing with their outputs.

Those inner functions cannot affect the values of `ant_row`, etc, because they only affect values inside themselves, and won't tell the outer function the new values unless you explicitly save and use the new values.  Not knowing exactly how those two inner functions are defined, it's hard to help further, but *assuming* they return new values for *row* and *col*, you *might* need something like this:

```
def move_ant(grid, ant_row, ant_col, orientation):

    new_row, new_col, new_orient = orientation_and_colour_change(ant_row,ant_col,orientation)

    newer_row, newer_col, newer_orient = movement(new_row,new_col,new_orient)

    return newer_row, newer_col, newer_orient
```

Comment: I would really not recommend naming your variables this way!

Comment: @ramseykhalaf, yes of course, it is for illustration purposes only.  Better practice would be updating the same variable (same name) in every case, as in: `row, col, orient = movement(row, col, orient)`

Comment: Hope you don't mind the comment, it's just I see so many programmers producing incomprehensible code that I wonder where they get their ideas from. So I think we should encourage answers to use good practices whenever possible!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code below.

```
def inner1(p):
    p.append(1)
def inner2(p):
    p += 1
def inner3(p):
    p = p + [1]
def outer(f, p):
    f(p)
    print p
outer(inner1, [0])
outer(inner2, 0)
outer(inner3, [0])
```

the output is

```
[0, 1]
0
[0]
```

this sample code indicates that when the inner function **changes** the **value** of a **mutable** object, say, `p.append(1)` to a list p, the change is permanent. But if the inner function only reassign a new object to the parameter p, the effect is only limited inside the inner function because the scope of a variable. The statement `p += 1` just reassign a immutable int object(which is 1 bigger than the original one) to the variable p. `p = p + [1]` for list is also a reassignment.